# Objective-c: UITableViewCell animation on scroll

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, animation

I'm currently experimenting with animations for **UITableViewCell**. So far everything is working fine, except for one 'issue'.

When I scroll through my UITableView a nice animation is displayed for the cells that are coming in. However when I tap one cell, the tableview reloads ([self.tableView reloadData]) and **the animation is displayed again for all visible cells**.

How can I force my tableview to **only show the animation on cells that are coming in**?

I'm using the UITableViewController function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

Anyone has suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be calling dataReload on tableView but only

```
[myUITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

to reload only cells that need it.

however if you animate them in tableview willDisplayCell you could ask whether that cell is currently visible and animate it only if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on [self.tableview reloaddata]. Removed all of them and only updated indexes that needed an update - performance++. I've been looking for an solution to check wether an cell is visible or not, but have not been able to find one working solution on that. Thanks for your comment!